# How to avoid Django sub thread being killed by uWSGI respawn

Tags: python, django, multithreading, uwsgi

I created a web server by Django + uWSGI. The basic flow is: when a request is received, Django will initiated a sub thread by python build-in lib "Threading" to write db asynchronously, and in main thread it will respond immediately back to client.

How, uWSGI sometimes will respawn the worker process(maybe when there is no request handling by the process?), which caused the background sub thread is also killed even when it's not finished yet. Any clue to avoid uWSGI not to respawn a worker process which has a running sub-thread?

uWSGI respawn log:

```
DAMN ! worker 4 (pid: 31161) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
```

uWSGI ini config (version 2.0.12):

```
[uwsgi]
# Django's wsgi file
wsgi-file   = /home/fh/dj_uwsgi/dj_site/dj_site/wsgi.py    
master      = true
processes   = 10
http       = :8001
threads = 2
enable-threads = true
http-timeout = 10     
max-requests = 5000        
chmod-socket    = 664
vacuum      = true    
pidfile = /home/fh/dj_uwsgi/dj_site/uwsgi.pid
daemonize = /home/fh/log/uwsgi_dj.log
```

Django(version 1.8) app pseudo code:

in handlers.py:

```
import threading

class SubThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    daemon = True

    def run(self):
        # actions to write db

def myHandler():
    my_sub_thread = SubThreadClass()
    my_sub_thread.start()
```

in views.py:

```
from handlers import myHandler

def url_handler(request): 
    myHandler()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why are you using threads in the first place?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I don't know what is XY problem. Would you please share more information? The reason why I use multi threads here is just to respond client as soon as possible so that it will not be blocked by db operations. @DanielRoseman

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - ie you're not asking about your actual problem. Manually managing threads is rarely a good idea in an environment you do not manage, as you have discovered. Use an offline worker system like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Celery can perfectly meet my requirement. Could you post your answer below so that I can accept it?

Comment: Celery is heavyweight if all you need are some things like this. If you have uwsgi, you can use its spooler process, and import uwsgidecorators to make it really really simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually dealing with threads is rarely a good idea in an environment you do not manage.

You should use an offline worker system like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was caused due to the delay of certain operations with my database.

I use **uWSGI** with **Pyramid** (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/). Since you are using Django (Python) it is very likely that solution works to you.

The settings cited below are in the configuration file **production.ini** (section **[uwsgi]**) (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html).

I "solved" this problem using the rules below. That rules "solve" the problem as its drastically reduces its occurrences. So far I have not seen anything to avoid it altogether. I also had an improvement in performance (need tests, but we evaluated as a good improvement). The solution is basically increasing the number of threads depending on how many connections your database allows (you can also increase the number of connections allowed by your database).

**Rules:**

TO DEFINE PROCESSES'S QUANTITY (**processes** parameter in your production.ini or equivalent)

```
q=n*2

q - number of processes
n - number of CPUs/cores
```

TO DEFINE THREADS'S QUANTITY (**threads** parameter  in your production.ini or equivalent)

```
t=(p*0.8)/q

t - number of threads
p - number of connections available in your database
q - number of processes
```

Note also that the **sqlalchemy.pool_size** parameter (if you use sqlalchemy http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) should be given the same value as t.

**Plus:**

To prevent Python processes from accessing your production.ini simultaneously when they are restarted causing a "lock" add the "lazy-apps=true" parameter in the [uwsgi] section. **Do this only if your system begins to have problems with it.**